# Phonegap Build, new BackgroundJS plugin

Tags: ios, cordova

Ok, I am having some issues, it might be just my understanding or how I have used the plugin for phonegap. This new plugin now listed on build.phonegaps website,

https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-background/tree/ab89bcb9287685092504e462501d131185ecb1e9 - sort of works but sort of does not.

The line below from the the plugins is in my 'ondeviceReady' call,

```
   window.plugins.BackgroundJS.LockBackgroundTime(function(){}, function(msg){console.log(msg);});
```

This sort of works, I have a timer, which runs in the background now, no problem but it stops the app from access anything, like the accelerometer and geo-location.

Is it the way I am using this app or is it because this is not meant to give me access to these api's?

Any help welcome,

Glenn,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with building on a Mac and opening it up within Xcode and selecting the 'Background Fetch' call, which seems to let the JavaScript access to the phones sensors.

Glenn.